# synonym request: "enclosure(s)" and "pens"

Tags: support, tag-synonyms

We have [enclosure](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/enclosure) and [pens](https://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pens), each with one question.  Can we (a) pluralize the former ("enclosures") and (b) make the latter a synonym of it?  "Enclosures" seems more general, and most of our counting-noun tags are plural.